# All background jobs failing with max concurrent job limit reached - Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a background job that runs every minute and it has been working fine for the last few weeks. All of a sudden when I log in today, every job is failing instantly with max concurrent job limit reached. I have tried deleting the job and waiting for 15 minutes so any job running currently can finish but when I schedule the job again it just starts failing every time like before. I don't understand why parse thinks I am running a job when I am not.

Comment: Just went to report this to parse. Looks like its a known bug that came up a couple of days ago and they are fixing it. Will leave this up until its fixed so other people can find out whats going on.

Comment: I am having the same issue. What can we do in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Someone deleted my previous answer (not sure why). This is and continues to be a Parse Bug. See this Google Group for other people reporting the issue (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/parse-developers/_TwlzCSosgk/KbDLHSRmBQAJ) there are several open Parse bugs about this as well.

Comment: The previous answer was deleted because it didn't actually answer the question in any way. Just a "me too" comment.

Comment: Didn't have enough rep to leave it as a comment! What gives?

Comment: Well, _this_ one has a bit of useful information, so it won't be deleted as quickly :)